# Как вывести различное количество записей в компоненте vue.js

Tags: vue.js

подскажите кто нибудь, у меня компонент используется как отдельная страница и как виджет на главной. Как мне отобразить в состояние виджета и странницы различное количество записей. Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос всего 3 день изучаю vue.js. Подскажите пример или статью какую либо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю вам подойдут [пропсы](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

В родителе указываете пропс:

```
<Articles items-in-component="3" />
```

В ребенке используете:

```
{
  name: "Articles",
  props: {
    itemsInComponent: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

теперь вы можете использовать его как обычное реактивное свойство `this.itemsInComponent`.